# OrderBy Clause to eloquent relationship field in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
Car
[
   name:ABC
   price:10
   relationship
  [
    category:car
  ]
]
Car
[
   name:XYZ
   price:10
   relationship
  [
    category:truck
  ]
]
```

i want to apply OrderBy Clause to category name

Comment: plz post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join like this:

```
Car::join("categories", "cars.id", "categories.id")->orderBy("categories.name")->get();
```